# Add an option to explain a rollback

Tags: feature-request, edits, rollbacks

I rolled back a major edit to [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128252/external-constants-for-uicolor-uifont-etc) today, but I found no place to put the reason I thought the edit was not appropriate.

In this case, I thought the edits would have been better if they we put into an answer, along with an explanation of why the suggestions make sense. I might even have offered to provide a bounty to the editor for providing a more up to date answer. But i have no way to communicate this in my rollback.

Or did I overlook something in the editor?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to leave a message for why you're rolling something back, you can click the **edit** button on whichever revision you wish to rollback to (it's right next to the rollback button you normally click). This will bring up the editing screen with that revision filled into all the boxes. Don't modify anything, and simply type your message into the edit reason box and save it. The post will be effectively rolled back to that revision, and the edit reason will have the "Rollback to Revision *x*" appended to the front of it like a normal rollback (so long as you made no other changes).

Note that in your revisions under activity (in your profile), this edit will be listed solely as "rolled back to a previous revision" - the custom reason will not show up there.

Comment: That's not very intuitive... TIL

Comment: No, it's not obvious at all. And in the case, the previous edit was simply some tag changes, so it can become pretty foggy what the sequence of the change history is. Adding the contemporaneous rollback/comment feature might also help prevent rollback conflicts.